# Adding a styled CSS button

Tags: css, button

I'm trying to add a button that will look something along the lines of the orange "Get It Now" button found here: https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/

The guides I found on the topic focus on specific themes which I don't use, and so I'm currently stuck. How can I do that?

My website: https://roi.pub

Thanks.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you please share your code

Comment: Please read 
[Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That button basically looks like a "btn-warning" from bootstrap with some width modifications...

Comment: Thanks guys. This is what I tried: http://kb.wpbeaverbuilder.com/article/166-add-buttons-to-your-navigation-menu and it had no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here a code snippet for the button. Add the css on the custom style of wordpress, and the class for the button in your menu item.

Don't be freaked about the font, it will get the font that is used in your theme.

```css
.menu-btn {
  background-color: #F7951E;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 18px 3px !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D4821F;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background .3s;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #D4821F;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu-btn" href="#"> Get It Now </a>
```

EDIT:

Code for you website's menu :

```
.menu-btn {
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: #F7951E;
  color: #fff !important;
  padding: 10px 18px 7px !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D4821F;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background .3s;
}
```

Comment: Finally! Something that works. Thanks man. But, one little thing, the button is huge; guess it's because of my theme. Take a look here: https://snag.gy/z2gaZl.jpg

Comment: If you can set the answer has accepted for futur users :)

Comment: Can you help me with reducing the size of the button?

Comment: Yup, as i see on your website, the "a" tags on your menu have a line height of 90px. So just for the button set the ligne height to 1 and add a margin-top to align it center. this is not the cleanest way but while i can't access your code, this is the best advice that i can give you :). Try some value from 20px to 60px and adjust it to be centered. Also the color is not the right color, I Think this is because of the color of the nav link. So change color: #fff to color: #fff !important.

Comment: this is what it looks like now : https://snag.gy/Hg9uFv.jpg 
I tried playing with the line height/margin but it just increases the white gap. No effect on the button itself...

Comment: line-height: 1 !important; margin-top: 25px; important;  padding: 10px 18px 7px !important;

Comment: Please set the css to your menu button just for a moment. So I can see the css in live.

Comment: Add this to your css .menu-btn a {
    line-height: 1;
    color: white;
}

Comment: Cool, it works. Can you now take a look on the sticky header? It didn't take effect there...

Comment: .sticky-header .sf-menu .menu-btn {margin-top: 10px !important;} .sticky-header .sf-menu .menu-btn > a { line-height: 1 !important;}

Comment: Actually one last thing. Really. The button is getting messed up in mobile view... what should I do about it? :

Comment: .nav-main .navbar-collapse .mobile-menu> li.menu-btn a {
    border-top: 0;
}

inspector-stylesheet:1
.nav-main .navbar-collapse .mobile-menu> li.menu-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

Comment: It says "Expected an IDENT or FUNCTION after COLON" on the first line of the code.. 
 
.nav-main .navbar-collapse

Comment: I helped you a lot, i makde a mistake when pasting it here but please try to figure it out by yourself, you will find what is going wrong in it...

Answer (score -1):

Try this
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMQNZE

```
button {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #F7951E;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 18px 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #D4821F;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    top: 2px;
}

button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #db7f0f;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can inspect any element from a page and see it's css attributes.